# How do I define a static value for a parameter of a new class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a model for a thing called a Lesson that has `:content` and a `:user_id`. For early builds of this app, I want the content to be changing, based on my entry, and for the user_id to always = 1 so that it's clean in the DB and there's not a nil value.

How do I go about this?

In my `lessons_controller.rb` I have this:

```
  def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(params[:lesson])
if @lesson.save
... do something
else 
... do something else
```

I'm guessing this would be the best place to define that the user_id = 1 but how should I go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set `@lesson.user_id = 1` in the line after you create it with `new`, and before you `save` it.

Another way to do it would be to set a hook in the lesson model -

```
before_validation :on => :create do |lesson|
  lesson.user_id = 1
end
```